# Wiki, Content Management or Roll my Own?

Tags: wiki, content-management-system

Oh, Collective Wisdom of the Crowd,

I've been handed ***the Task***. My inclination is to go code but as I'm old and weary I'm aware of my total ignorance in Web coding, as well as my tendency to code instead of using off-the-shelf parts (a.k.a. NIH) and the similarity of ***the Task*** to the problems solves with Wikis and Content Management Systems. So, my question is: Solve the Task using a Wiki, A Content Management System or roll my own site?

***The Task***:

I've videoed a three-days sports event of my Ninjutsu club, and have created a set of three DVDs, containing many "chapters". Most chapters consist of an explanation and demonstration of a technique, followed by the instructor moving around and correcting people.

The big Honcho would like some of the senior students to review the DVDs prior to production.

One way would be to reproduce a few sets of the DVDs, mail said students, and have them e-mail me their comments. This, however, is low tech, not sexy, and I'm sure would not generate the desired involvement.

As an alternative I thought about creating a web site for this purpose, with the added value that the web site would later, upon release, serve as a companion to the DVD. First-draft requirements appear to be:

- Allow each reviewer to pick up the part of the material he’s "the owner of" (i.e. responsible for).
- Provide a web page for each DVD chapter, together with a navigation system.
- Upon creation each page will contain and embedded video of that chapter.
- Allow each owner to mark her sections as “OK”, “With Issues” or “Remove”.
- Direct reviewers to pages with sections having problems, or not-yet-reviewed, or with high activity (i.e. interesting).
- Allow reviewers to collectively document the techniques demonstrated in the video sequences, especially during the corrections when the instructor can’t be clearly heard as the speakers are turned off. Upond release this documentation will be "frozen" and provide additional insight into the technique, in addition to what was provided in the event.
- Generate the basis for sub-titles.
- In addition to above documentation, each such page will also contain discussions between the reviewers concerning the technique. These discussions will be visible on the page, below the video and the documentation, unlike Wikipedia where the discussions appear on different tabs.
- When documenting the techniques, the instructors will be able to create and use a collection of terms – names for the techniques. These names will be collected into a central ontology, together with their translation, and will later be used to index the content.
- Hebrew support of the content is mandatory
- The site will have the ability to contain translated versions of the content where the
  user can choose the language she will use. So after release a Spanish speaking student who have purchased the DVD and gone to the site would be able to look at a Spanish translation of the documentation.

I know, I know this is a tall order and [I'm only an egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land#cite_note-7) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick with the email for the review; ninjas <3 email. Enforce participation through intimidation. Focus on shortening the time-to-release, IMO.

Use the time to figure out if creating an online back-end is worth it for the release--even a good martial arts video doesn't sell a lot of copies; if you're not Hatsumi or Hayes, even less.

It looks like the biggest requirement is I18N and comments.

I'd go with a Wiki; its collaborative model of content creation is perfect for things like this, and many support translations--although keeping up with the translating can be problematic. [Wiki gardening](https://www.socialtext.net/exchange/wiki_gardening_tips) is time-consuming and non-trivial, adding a layer of translation...

Although it'd give a whole new meaning to ninja edits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Greatly appreciated. Probably as wise as it was amusing to read and fun to decode. 

Probably clever to stick to email, but trying to intimidate the reviewers wouldn't work - they're much more intimidating than I an :)

Waiting for other opinions.

Comment: Re. "Worth it" - For me it's really a labor of love. The big guy - I assume he would like to make an earning, but this does not appear to the main concern. And the DVD IS good content. So "worth it" - if it provides great added value for the people studying the DVD, without ruining my life and my wallet - it's good value.

Answer (score 1):

Potential revenue or the emotional investment will dictate the scope of the project, but here's a couple of ideas to consider:

- Ticketing system to allocate the work to users, track progress, define state of completion. I recommend the open source [Request Tracker](http://www.bestpractical.com/rt/). This would be the easier option to implement in terms of management of the project, but doesn't touch on the l18n or the web development.

OR

- A Component Content Management System to act as database and publishing tool. I would suggest the open source [Pressgang CCMS](http://pressgang-ccms.github.com/). This would take more effort to implement but offers the features of Request Tracker with the addition of publishing output functionality (especially in terms of the use of [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) XML and [Publican](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Publican)). It is also built to work with the open source translation tool [Zanata](http://zanata.org/).